# How to send OAuth2 Access token from IOS 7 to google blobstore using AFNNetworking API

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, blobstore

From iPhone i am trying to  send oAuth Access token as http header to upload image  to google blobstore service  .I got the blob upload url fine but when I try to upload image  I am getting NullPointer exception in upload handler servlet, saying user is null .I am using AFNNetwokring API . I pasted Exception and IOS code below .Please help.Thanks in advance.

> NullPointer exception java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at com.allyouralbums.servlets.AppContext.getCurrentUser(AppContext.java:91)
>   at com.allyouralbums.servlets.UploadHandlerServlet.doPost(UploadHandlerServlet.java:45)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

```
- (void)postImage :(UIImage *) image
toUploadURI:(NSString*) blobServiceURL
withAuthentication:(GTMOAuth2Authentication*) auth{
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5);
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager.requestSerializer setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Bearer %@", [auth   accessToken]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
[manager POST: blobServiceURL parameters:nil  constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
[formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:@"FromIos" fileName:@"FromIos" mimeType:@"image/jpg;"];
 } success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
   NSLog(@"Success: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

}

Comment: I up-voted because I am having the same problem. Have you resolved this issue? I am having the same problem. I am trying to send an image to blobstore along with String metadata for the image. I am not able to send the metadata because its always null on server: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25102155/afhttprequestoperationmanager-post-multi-part-request-not-working and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25110365/how-to-convert-nsstring-to-uiimage-for-appengine-blobstore